# Using Parse Path as Variable in Calculate Field with ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder

I am trying to use the PPName field in Calculate Field, but it errors each time.

[image]

I had added %PPName% in the calculate field code box for Arcade.

Is there something else I need to do to be able to add this value to a field when processing a Calculate Field Process?

It specifically says that it is not defined.

=== UPDATE ===
Per the suggestion of Hornbydd I added the %PPName% as a precondition of the calculate field process. Below are the errors and images showing the changes.
[image]
[image]

Error Message
[image]

Comment: Make PPName a precondition to the Calculate Field tool to ensure the Parse Path tool runs before the Calculate field tool.

Comment: I went through and followed your suggestion and still got an error - I have added comments to my original post for your review

Comment: If PPName is text then enclose your inline substitution in double quotes so calculate is `"%PPNAME%"`.

Comment: Hornbydd - that was the solution. Thank you!